# Active record only saving time stamps not record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi trying to save a record directly from the model

```
attr_accessor :file, :current_user, :file_name, :user_id

def create_record_and_save_attachment
    record = Report.new(file_name: file.original_filename, user_id: current_user.id)
    if record.save
      record.attachment.attach(file)
    end
end
```

dont know why it is only saving timestamps.

getting this

```
Report Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "reports" ("created_at", "updated_at")
```

please note i and getting values for file and current_user

Comment: Are you sure that `file.original_filename` and `current_user.id` are not nil?

Comment: You don't mention any params. If you get your file and other data from the frontend you need to call things like `record.attachment.attach(params[:report][:file])` Et ..

Comment: you're using `attr_accessor` for `:file_name, and :user_id`... are you sure you've these columns in the database?

Comment: ^ If so, remove the `attr_accessor`s for `:file_name` and `:user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information here to diagnose the problem because what you've done in the code you've provided is fine. It's likely that there is a problem in the code for your model and/or the `file_name` and `user_id` columns do not exist in your database.